# error: incompatible types: unexpected return value : Java 8

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I have written a simple method which returns the boolean value.

```
private boolean isActionAvailable(Collection<StudentConfiguration> studentConfigs){
       if(studentConfigs != null)
        {
            studentConfigs.forEach(studentConfig -> {
                if(studentConfig.action() == null || !studentConfig.action().equals(Action.DELETE)) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The method is throwing the following  exception .

```
error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
            studentConfigs.forEach(studentConfig ->
```

What's the problem with my code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The lambda expression passed to `forEach` shouldn't have a return value.

It looks like you want to return `true` if any of the elements of the input `Collection` satisfies a condition:

```
private boolean isActionAvailable(Collection<StudentConfiguration> studentConfigs){
    if(studentConfigs != null) {
        if (studentConfigs.stream().anyMatch(sc -> sc.action() == null || !sc.action().equals(Action.DELETE))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

As Holger suggested, this can be reduced to a single statement:

```
return studentConfigs != null && studentConfigs.stream().anyMatch(sc -> sc.action() == null || !sc.action().equals(Action.DELETE));
```

or

```
return studentConfigs != null ? studentConfigs.stream().anyMatch(sc -> sc.action() == null || !sc.action().equals(Action.DELETE)) : false;
```

Comment: Why not a simple enhanced forloop? When do you choose one over the other?

Comment: @LukeGarrigan Enhanced for loop would also be fine. As to which one to choose, I'd go for the one more readable to you (and to other developers that may read your code). I think using `anyMatch` in this example better expresses what the method is doing, which is to find whether any of the elements of the input collection satisfies some condition.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you, I ask because not many developers I work with use anyMatch so it's almost a little foreign to me. Thanks for that.

Comment: @LukeGarrigan Java is an evolving language. Higher order functions are working their way in. I would suggest you embrace them, rather than get left behind

Comment: Absolutely @Alexander The one potential quarrel I have with it is readability, to me and I suspect most programmers an enhanced forloop is more readable, but then I suppose it's just because I don't use it as often as I potentially should.

Comment: @LukeGarrigan "I suppose it's just because I don't use it as often as I potentially should." Yep, pretty much. This is the future of Java, so you'll only see more and more of these higher order functions.

Comment: @LukeGarrigan well, you would use `collection.contains(obj)` instead of looping over the collection to test each element for equality, wouldn’t you? So `collection.stream().anyMatch(condition)` is just a generalization of the idea, when the condition is more complex than plain equality.

Answer (score 5):

I don't recommend you use Stream API here. Look at how clear and simple the `foreach` version is:

```
private boolean isActionAvailable(Collection<StudentConfiguration> studentConfigurations) {
    if(studentConfigurations == null) {
        return false;
    }

    for (StudentConfiguration configuration : studentConfigurations) {
        if (!Action.DELETE.equals(configuration.action())) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Otherwise, if you are a fanatic guy,

```
private boolean isActionAvailable(Collection<StudentConfiguration> configs) {
    return configs != null &&
           configs.stream()
                  .map(StudentConfiguration::action)
                  .anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual​(Action.DELETE).negate()));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively with Java9 and above you can use [`Stream.ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#ofNullable(T)) and update as:

```
private boolean isActionAvailable(Collection<StudentConfiguration> studentConfigs) {
    return Stream.ofNullable(studentConfigs)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .anyMatch(studentConfig -> studentConfig.action() == null || !studentConfig.action().equals(Action.DELETE));
}
```

Comment: It’s debatable whether `Stream.ofNullable(studentConfigs) .flatMap(Collection::stream) …` is simpler than `studentConfigs != null && studentConfigs.stream() …`

Comment: @Holger By *simpler* here you meant readability aspect or performance as well? Readability I believe would be opinion based, I find it easy to read now, maybe sometimes back I wouldn't have.

Comment: I only meant readability when I wrote the comment, but now that you’re asking… There is the lack-of-laziness issue with `flatMap` which still exists in Java 9, which would be a reason not to use your variant before Java 10. But in recent versions, I wouldn’t think about any remaining minor performance differences.

Answer (score 4):

This is signature of forEach() method `forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)` .
It takes reference of Consumer interface which has method `void accept(T t)`. 
In your code you are overriding `accept()` and returning a value which is not valid as `accept()` has void return type.
Therefore it is showing error

```
 error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
            studentConfigs.forEach(studentConfig ->
```

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement in your lambda will terminate that lambda, not the `isActionAvailable()` method. Therefore, the inferred type of the lambda is now wrong, because `forEach` expects a `Consumer`.

See the other answers for how to solve that problem.